# AcceptButton won't close form

Tags: c#, winforms, acceptbutton

I have two forms that are very similar, but in one of them clicking the `AcceptButton` closes the form, and in the other it doesn't close the form. Both of them have their `AcceptButton` set to `btnAccept`.

I recently created the second one, the first one has existed for awhile and was created by someone else.

They are both opened this way:

```
using(var form = new SomeDialog(dependency))
{
    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    form.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Both of them handle the accept button click along these lines.

```
private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _dependency.DoSomething(userInput);
}
```

Posting my entire designer file probably wouldn't be helpful. Is there something in particular that'd be helpful to show from it? I couldn't find a similar post on StackOverflow.

What am I missing that's causing the divergent behavior?

Comment: The form would need its AcceptButton property set to btnAccept.

Comment: Both forms have their `AcceptButton` property set to `btnAccept`.

Comment: Then is the event wired up?  Does the code run when clicked?

Comment: Yes, breakpoints in the `btnAccept_Click` are getting hit as expected. In one, the form closes afterwards, in the other, it stays open.

Comment: Then you have to set the form's DialogResult to OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AcceptButton property just selects the button that will implement the default action when you press the Enter key.  Clearly visible in the UI with a heavy border around the button.  But that isn't enough, you still have to *implement* the default action.

A simple way is to set the button's DialogResult property in the designer.  Which is okay but tends to cause surprises when your event handler does something like validate the dialog content, you'd have to set the form's DialogResult property back to None when you're not happy.  I personally prefer to always set the form's DialogResult explicitly in the Click event handler.  That's debuggable code, let's me see why it "doesn't work".